# android sdk tablelayout alignment

Tags: android, tablelayout

I have been having problems with my table alignment which I can't fix. It's driving me crazy trying to fix this layout. Here's my `main.xml`:

```
<TableLayout
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <TableRow>
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="40sp"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
        android:text="From" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/input"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="numberDecimal|numberSigned" >

        <requestFocus />
    </EditText>
</TableRow>

<Spinner
    android:id="@+id/spinner1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="To" />

<Spinner
    android:id="@+id/spinner2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />


        <TableRow>
<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:onClick="onClick"
    android:text="Formula" />

 <Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
    android:layout_width="80dp"
    android:layout_column="1"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:onClick="onClick"
    android:text="Convert" />
</TableRow>


<TextView
    android:id="@+id/output"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Medium Text"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/op"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Small Text"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />
 </TableLayout>
```

I want it to look like this:

[image link here http://imageshack.us/a/img818/5928/3wo5.png](http://imageshack.us/a/img818/5928/3wo5.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try [this](http://pastie.org/8396331)

the layout is in there.

Comment: its still the same for me, the "From" textview is still conquering the space thats why i cant resize the edit text to make it wider

Comment: try this, since the edit text is in the relative layout, set the edittext toLeft property to the button , and set the button's alignParentRight property to true. this way the edit text will take up the remaining space (thats the complete length)